# jQuery- Adding class to several elements depending on another element’s attribute value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class=“item”>
    <div class=“title”>......</div>
    <div class=“description”>......</div>
    <div class=“link”>.
        <a href=“destination_1”> .... </a>
    </div>
</div>



<div class=“item”>
    <div class=“title”>......</div>
    <div class=“description”>......</div>
    <div class=“link”>.
        <a href=“destination_2”> .... </a>
    </div>
</div>



<div class=“item”>
    <div class=“title”>......</div>
    <div class=“description”>......</div>
    <div class=“link”>.
        <a href=“destination_3”> .... </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to add an extra class to .title, .description and .link  depending on the value of href. This is how it is supposed to look like:

```
<div class=“item”>
    <div class=“title dest1”>......</div>
    <div class=“description dest1”>......</div>
    <div class=“link dest1”>.
        <a href=“destination_1”> .... </a>
    </div>
</div>



<div class=“item”>
    <div class=“title dest2”>......</div>
    <div class=“description dest2”>......</div>
    <div class=“link dest2”>.
        <a href=“destination_2”> .... </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

.... and so on

Thank you

Comment: On a side note, check the quotes in your code as well. `“item”` isn't using the correct format of `'` or `"`.

Comment: Why do you need incremental class attributes? The idea goes against their purpose, and sounds like this is an attempt to solve an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your destinations are and how you want to pair them together with your classes, maybe this could be what you're looking for:

```
$('a[href="destination_1"]').closest('.item').children().addClass('dest1');
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/0w76dwc0/

Comment: So if there are 1000 of these he should have 1000 lines of jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 well, if there's a pattern between the URL and the classes you could modify the rule above to cover them all. I just don't have the info about such a pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I was trying conditionals and driving myself crazy...

Comment: @j08691 It works because (I forgot to mention) I only have 8 different destinations...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('.item').children().addClass(function() {
    return $(this).addClass('dest' + $(this).parent().index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <div class="title">......</div>
    <div class="description">......</div>
    <div class="link">.
        <a href="destination_1"> .... </a>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="item">
    <div class="title">......</div>
    <div class="description">......</div>
    <div class="link">.
        <a href="destination_2"> .... </a>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="item">
    <div class="title">......</div>
    <div class="description">......</div>
    <div class="link">.
        <a href="destination_3"> .... </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You assume that the number is only a index value, but is that really the case? I read "destination_1" as potentially any valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of...

```
var items = $('body').find('.item');

items.each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var href = self.attr('href');

    if(//YOUR CONDITION with href//)
    {
        self.find('.title').addClass('dest1');
        self.find('.decription').addClass('dest1');
        self.find('.link').addClass('dest1');
    }

    // etc

});
```

And check what **j08691** said!